# How do I get "10 vulnerable machine kills"?

Tags: achievements, horizon-zero-dawn

While the trophy description seems extremely straightforward, I think there is more to it than it sounds. The description is simply:

> Killed 10 Machines weak to Fire while burning, or weak to Freeze while frozen.

However, I've taken out 6-7 Corrupted Zones by setting all Machines within them on fire and made sure to let them die while burning. At this point, I'd estimate that I've killed at least 20-30 Machines weak to Fire while they were burning, yet this trophy hasn't popped. Do I need to kill them with non-elemental damage while they're burning/frozen to get the trophy or something?

Comment: The way its worded, it almost sounds like *you* have to be the one who is frozen/on fire.

Comment: @TimmyJim ...I wasn't even thinking about *that* interpretation... now I **really** am not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: [Reading around](https://psnprofiles.com/trophy/5879-horizon-zero-dawn/5-10-vulnerable-machine-kills), it looks like some sort of circle appears above a machines head and will fill up indicating when it is burning or freezing. When the circle is full, let the machine die.

Comment: @TimmyJim that's what I'd been doing... which is why I'm confused

Comment: You don't seem to be the only one having this issue.  People have said to just keep playing the game and you are bound to just get it through normal play.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the trophy after killing 10 Corrupted machines with burning damage such that the `+100 Burning Kill` text appeared on screen.  (I was not myself on fire at the time.)

Because I originally assumed the exact opposite based on the text of the trophy -- that the machine would have to be on fire and then I would have to kill it by some other means -- I was quite surprised when the trophy popped.

Comment: Yes, I believe that it has to be the burning damage that kills the enemy. So if you have a Scrapper that is on fire for most of it's hitpoints, but you go in and melee it for the final blow, it won't count, because it wasn't the `burning` that killed it. You also don't receive any `Burning Kill` experience.

Answer (score 1):

I think the game may have a flaw where corrupted machines do not count as "vulnerable to fire" machines for the purposes of quests and trophies.  I tried to finish a tutorial "vulnerable to fire" quest and none of the corrupted machines seemed to count.  I switched to an uncorrupted machine marked as fire vulnerable and it worked fine.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment on the accepted answer rather than a separate one.

Comment: I actually disagree with that answer.  I don't think that would work unless the corrupted machines were machines vulnerable to fire in their uncorrupted forms.  I think the answerer likely got lucky in the machines being killed when the trophy tripped were Sawtooths or some such.